# can backend update user query(mutation) in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I have a scenario which I don't know how to handle in GraphQL way:

A user is asking for creating a reservation, the query is `mutation booking(date: "20190101", userId: "1"){confNumber}`, backend needs to send an SMS message to this user after the reservation is confirmed. But there is no phone number in the response of the booking API, so if I can update this query to `mutation booking(date: "20190101", userId: "1"){confNumber, guest{phoneNumber}}` then I can get the phone number and send SMS in an API hook.

Briefly, is there a way to do this implicit query addition? to help backend insert some necessary field to a query(mutation). And it is a return field from a mutation, so I can not make it as a required element.

Comment: If the backend is resolving the `guest` and `phoneNumber` fields, why could it not query the db (or whatever your data source is) for that information as part of the mutation? Is this question specific to some specific implementation of GraphQL or some tool based on it?

Comment: @DanielRearden query DB for a phone number after the reservation is created is an additional operation. if I can merge these step into one is better.